# Achieve AVRCP using Pybluez in Linux

Tags: python, bluetooth, avrcp

I want to make my PC as AVRCP bluetooth controller (CT) and handle a device which supports AVRCP bluetooth  profile This has to be done using python scripting. Can I achieve this from pyBluez. If yes can some one give me some pointer of how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Linux Bluetooth Stack supporting AVRCP. See [here](http://www.bluez.org/about/).

There seems to be an implementation of AVRCP in Python [here](http://www.koders.com/python/fid100E28CBE04953D5337352954ED5D4D5D8037506.aspx?s=cdef%3Atimer).

Have a look at it and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also exploring this area. Further to the links provided by Radu, I've found https://trac.ctdo.de/ctdo/browser/btctl/src/pyavrcp which appears to implement the controller (CT) side of AVRCP, as well as the target (player).

Comment: Link is broken.. any chance to still have the source code?